# Twitter4j 3.x Oauth 1.1

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

**Twitter** has switched to `Oauth 1.1` and I have an application I'm writing on android that *uses* `twitter4j 2.x` which doesn't support `Oauth 1.1`

and recommendation says that I should upgrade to `twitter4j 3.x` which does support `OAuth 1.1`.

Do I still need to modify my code or I should just upgrade the library?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, it's only a matter of upgrading the library.